# How can I identify the most predictive factors?

Tags: predictive-modeling, random-forest, decision-trees

I've been playing around with bagged trees and random forests. How can I tell what factors most influenced the categorization? Will scikitlearn just spit it out, or is it trickier than that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It basically lies within the fitted object.

```
model.fit(X, y)
importances = model.feature_importances_
```

The importances are in the same order as the columns of features ($X$).